# jQuery, how to play animation when element is on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

Browser plays animations at the same time when it reaches the point. That's not what I want. The browser have to play every animation separated.

This is my jQuery code:

```
function initScrollAnimation (){

    $('.slideLeft').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() + $(window).height() - 500;
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){
                $( ".slideLeft" ).addClass('active');
            }; //else {
                //$( ".slideLeft" ).removeClass('active');
            //};
    }); 

    $('.slideRight').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() + $(window).height() - 500;
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){
                $( ".slideRight" ).addClass('active');
            }; //else {
                //$( ".slideLeft" ).removeClass('active');
            //};
    }); 

}
```

And this is the css code

```
.slideLeft{
    margin-left:-25%;
}

    .slideRight{
        margin-right:-25%;
    }

.slideLeft.active{
    margin-left: 0%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

    .slideRight.active{
        margin-right: 0%;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    }
```

Comment: You can use the [Waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) library to do stuff when an element is reached by scrolling

Comment: "when it reaches the point" When what reaches which point?

Answer (score 0):

Alter the transition times for the objects

```
.slideLeft{
    margin-left:-25%;
}

    .slideRight{
        margin-right:-25%;
    }

.slideLeft.active{
    margin-left: 0%;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in;
}

    .slideRight.active{
        margin-right: 0%;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

or use a timeout function for one of the divs:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('.slideRight').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() + $(window).height() - 500;
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object){
                $( ".slideRight" ).addClass('active');
            }; //else {
                //$( ".slideLeft" ).removeClass('active');
            //};
    }); 
}, 200);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the answer is not what i was looking for. I have two sections under each other with booth a slideLeft and slideRight div. When the first div is on screen the animation start for the first div and second but the second div is not on screen.I want that the browser the animation separated start when the div is on screen

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you have elements in different positions (vertically) and want to trigger the animation for an element when it becomes visible:

Just replace `$( ".slideLeft" ).addClass('active');` with `$(this).addClass('active');`

as at the moment you are checking the position of one of the `.slideLeft` and then adding the `active` class to all of the `.slideLeft` elements

same with `.slideRight`

Comment: doesn't work.. i can work with different div names but thats to easy